# Can IntelliJ show a dependency diagram for gradle projects?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

There is this functionality for maven projects where you can show an editable dependency tree for maven. The feature is presented in [this article](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/05/maven-dependencies-diagram/).

Does this feature somehow work with gradle or is there a similar feature?

Comment: There is gradle view plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7150-gradle-view also there is a related ticket, please upvote: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-183792

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible at the moment, there is a ticket which you can vote for: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-183792